# Structuremap injecting different implementation based on source class

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

Lets say i have the following setup

```
public interface IDocuments {}
public interface IPeople {}

public class Documents : IDocuments 
{
    public Documents(IRepository repo){ ... };
}

public class People : IPeople 
{
    public People(IRepository repo) { ... }
}

public class Controller1 
{
    public Controller1(IDocuments documents){}
}

public class Controller2
{
    public Controller2(IDocuments documents, IPeople people){}
}
```

How can I setup StructureMap to inject a different transient instance of IRepository into the dependency chain for Controller1 and for Controller2.

So to clarify:

There should be 2 instances of IRepository.

The first instance will be injected into the documents instance for controller1.

The second instance will be injected into Documents and People instances for controller2.

Comment: I believe IDocuments would be different instances, and therefore IRepository would have injected different instances.

Comment: Yeah they would have to be different instances.